# Why do we have to "take the derivative" of an abs function in order to get the critical points?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Why do we have to "take the derivative" of an abs function in order to get the critical points?

For almost every single abs function I've seen, if you just take off the parenthesis and take the derivative, you get the same answer as if you go through the whole $(x^2)^{1/2}$ thingy.

NOT EVERY SINGLE ONE! Mainly quadratics inside of abs functions.
ones like $x|x^2-3x+2|$

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually asking about. Differentiation is a fairly *convenient* (but not necessarily required) tool for studying critical points via the formula $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}|x|=\frac{x}{|x|}=\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x>0\\-1,&x<0\end{cases}$$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. But again, nobody will force you to use differentiation unless the problem explicitly states to do so.

Comment: so what I'm saying is, for the function that I put in my question is: if you treat the ABS as just normal parenthesis, and take the derivative, you get the same zeros as you would if you do the $(x^2)^(1/2)$ stuff.
Is there no pattern there? just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable. Then it is not hard to check that

$$ \bigl[ f(x)|g(x)| \bigr]' = \operatorname{sgn}(g(x)) \bigl[ f(x)g(x) \bigr]' \qquad \text{whenever} \quad g(x) \neq 0. $$

In particular, for $x$ satisfying $g(x) \neq 0$, we have the following equivalence:

$$ \bigl[ f(x)|g(x)| \bigr]' = 0 \qquad \iff \qquad \bigl[ f(x) g(x) \bigr]' = 0. $$

This tells that any critical points of $f(x)|g(x)|$, away from the zeros of $g$, are also critical points of $f(x)g(x)$. This justifies the trick mentioned by OP.

Keep in mind, however, that this argument tells *nothing* about the criticality of $f(x)|g(x)|$ at the zeros of $g$. Indeed, in OP's example, the graph of $y=x|x^2 - 3x + 2|$ looks like:

[image: graphs]

So, the derivative of $x(x^2 - 3x + 2)$ can only detects two critical points $x=1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, missing the remaining critical points $x = 1, 2$:

[image: graphs of derivatives]

Comment: I see, thank you!
Is it just a coincidence that if you factored the original  equation you would  get x = 2 and x = 1?